# In all NxN non-isomorphic binary matrices, how many matrices contains M non-zero digits?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

In all 2x2 non-isomorphic binary matrices:

```
[[0 0]  [[0 0]  [[0 0]  [[0 1]  [[0 1]  [[1 1]
 [0 0]]  [0 1]]  [1 1]]  [1 0]]  [1 1]]  [1 1]].
```

- There is 1 matrix that contains only 1 non-zero digit;
- There are 2 matrices that contain only 2 non-zero digits;
- There is 1 matrix that contains only 3 non-zero digits;
- There is 1 matrix that contains only 4 non-zero digits;

Non-isomorphic matrix is a set of matrices under the action of the dihedral group of the square D_4, referring to https://oeis.org/A054247

In general, for NxN non-isomorphic binary matrices, how many matrices are there that contain only M non-zero digits?

Comment: What are isomorphic matrices?

Comment: @abx  Matrices under the action of the dihedral group of the square D_4; or Matrices that can be expressed by rotation or row- column-mirroring, or transpose.

Comment: apply Burnside formula

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks for the help. Could you be more specific?

Comment: $D_4$ acts on matrices with $M$ 1's, you should count the number of orbits

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you very much for more elaboration. It is a bit difficult for me to follow as I am very new to the group theory; I would be grateful if you could write a full answer below.

Comment: Start with reading thus https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma

Comment: The numbers you want are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A054252 ... why the "Hamming-distance" tag?

Comment: Have you had a look at that link, Jakob?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh sorry, I missed that link. That's actually exactly the problem as of this. It also matches with Gordon Royle's answer. Thanks a lot!! The relation to hamming distance is, that matrices containing M non-zero digits have a hamming distance M to the zero matrices. This problem generalizes the hamming bound to have symmetric constraints rather than just having C(x, y) binary strings where x is the length of the binary string, and y is another binary string with a hamming distance to the given string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code, in Magma, that will produce a generating function that counts the number of binary matrices up to $D_4$-equivalence according to the number of 1s.

```
genFunc := function(n)
    s := Sym(n*n);
    cells := [[i,j] : i in [0..n-1], j in [0..n-1]];
    transpose := s![Position(cells,[j,i]) : i in [0..n-1], j in [0..n-1]];
    rotation := s![Position(cells,[j,n-1-i]) : i in [0..n-1], j in [0..n-1]];
    g := sub<s|[transpose,rotation]>;
    cp := CycleIndexPolynomial(g);
    P<x> := PolynomialRing(RationalField());
    vars := [1+x^i : i in [1..4]];
    gf := Evaluate(cp,vars);
    return gf;
end function;
```

It first creates permutations corresponding to rotation and transpose as they act on $n^2$ cells of an $n\times n$ grid.

Then it computes constructs the group generated by those permutations, as a subgroup of $S_{n^2}$.

Then it calculates the cycle index polynomial of this group, using a completely undocumented function in Magma. (The function is there and it works, but it is not in the documentation.)

According to Polyá's Enumeration Theorem (and/or Redfield if you prefer), substituting $1+x^i$ for the variable $x[i]$ gives a generating function where the coefficient of $x^i$ is the number of $D_4$-orbits of binary matrices with $i$ ones.

This needs a small amount of fiddling around to tell Magma that I want a polynomial ring with variable $x$.

If I now run `genFunc(2)` I get

```
x^4 + x^3 + 2*x^2 + x + 1
```

where $2x^2$ means that there are $2$ (equivalence classes of) binary matrices with $2$ ones.

If I now do `genFunc(3)`, I get

```
x^9 + 3*x^8 + 8*x^7 + 16*x^6 + 23*x^5 + 23*x^4 + 16*x^3 + 8*x^2 + 3*x + 1
```

meaning that there are, for example, 16 equivalence classes with exactly $6$ ones.

We can check that everything is ok, by substituting $x=1$ into the generating function, which will just give the total count, which can be compared to the OEIS entry you mentioned.

```
> gf := genFunc(5);
> Evaluate(gf,1);
4211744
```

Now of course, you are very unlikely to have access to Magma, which is a commercial product, but with the webpages that Fedor pointed out to you, and this code as a template, you should be able to implement this in either GAP or SageMath.

Comment: Everyone has access to Magma: [it is online here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

Comment: Ah yes, everyone can get 120 cpu seconds of Magma, which may suffice for a few cases.